# highpoint rr640l raid 5 status disable, having difficulty with recover

Tags: raid, raid5, data-recovery

I have been using a Highpoint RR640L controller (at BIOS version 1.5) for a couple years or more on my primary system.  The RAID-5 volume contains 4 disks, 2TB each.

This week, one of the disks failed, and showed as "missing" on the RR640L display (and in WebGUI).  I have since replaced the drive but cannot seem to successfully use the Recover link (found within the "Logical" Tab).  I click "Maintenance," and a small window allows me to chose Delete, Unplug or Recover.  When choosing Recover, I get a "some disks do not exist" message.

This occurs whether I have the placed disk in the Spare pool or not.  (The system does indeed see the extra disk, and will allow me to add it to and remove it from the spare pool successfully.  It also offers to make that disk a RAID set of its own [!!].)

But the actual RAID set remains in "Disable" mode and I cannot seem to fix it.

There seems to be no help for RR640L within WebGUI at all anymore; it's like HighPoint has left it behind.

I welcome your advice.

Comment: I neglected to mention originally: I have also initialized the new disk; that seemed to have no effect, though, on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally broke down and rebuilt the array, losing all data.  High Point didn't seem to care either way and I did not find an answer.  Sorry, but this question is a dead end.

I will concentrate my efforts on finding a reliable alternative (LSI used to be be great, but they've sold, and then sold again, I think).  Adaptec may still be an option.  If I remember after finding a better solution, I'll come back and update this.